# How to Reset or Restart applications in Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, themes

I just installed Debian 12.This is my specs

[image]

I'm very beginner in linux like 2 months old. With all tutorials and support I'm able to got to this point.

My issue is When Changed Theme ***Adwaita Dark Theme*** I was told every application related to gnome will change to dark theme but many applications like Rhythm Music Player, Pulse Volume center remained in white theme. I folded and didn't do nothing.

After a while I accidently uninstalled RhythmBox Music Player and Reinstalled it again but it was in dark theme default. I understood that I can get dark theme if I uninstall and reinstall it again but I don't want to do that way. Is there any way just to update theme to all application

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the application's kind and your particular needs, there are several ways to reset or restart it in Debian 12. You can try some of the typical methods listed below:

Using the Terminal: You can restart a programme using the command-line interface if you know the name of the application or its process. Use the killall command and the application's name in a terminal window after opening one. For instance, you may use the following command to restart the Firefox web browser:
Code copy

Stop all Firefox
The application will be stopped once you run this command, and you can relaunch it.

Using the System Monitor: Debian frequently comes with a system monitor tool that lets you manage processes that are currently executing, such as GNOME System Monitor or htop.

Restarting the X server: The Debian graphical user interface is managed by the X server, which you may occasionally need to restart. By pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, you may achieve this by navigating to a virtual terminal. Enter your username and password to log in, then run the next command to restart the X server:

arduino
Copies the command sudo systemctl restart display-manager
By pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 or F8, you can return to the graphical interface when the X server has restarted.

Before restarting or resetting apps, keep in mind that you may lose data in the process, so be sure to save any unsaved work. Additionally, depending on the desktop environment you choose, Debian 12's precise tools and techniques may change.
The system monitor may be started from the programme menu or by typing the necessary command into the terminal. Locate the programme you wish to restart in the list of open processes by opening the system monitor, selecting it, and selecting the option to end or kill the process. The programme can then be relaunched properly after that.

Logging out and back in: If you're having trouble using a number of programmes or the desktop environment as a whole, logging out and back in may be able to assist. To log out, select "Logout" or "Sign Out" from the system menu or press Ctrl+Alt+Del on your keyboard. After logging out and back in again, the desktop environment and programmes should both restart.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall-reinstall to see the changes, just close the app and open it again. If your using a desktop environment like gnome or KDE it should be pretty obvious how to do this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).